# Should support questions about recently-announced-on-blog features be asked on the blog, or in Meta?

Tags: discussion, blog

So Jeff just posted today that [account association has become automated](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/). I read the article, great thing to have, but I had an inkling of curiosity on it that I couldn't test myself (considering a few days back I went and setup all associations already). Unlike a feature request, bug report, or discussion topic that is traditionally directed towards the community as a whole, a support question about the new feature is probably excellently directed at the fellow who just announced the feature. Given the time proximity to the announcement, I could ask the question on the blog as a comment, knowing (if it's a sensible enough question) that Jeff would answer it with a satisfactory answer in due time. But alternatively, I could ask it on Meta, where others could contribute their findings. Which do you all think is a better approach? Or is it in fact a better idea to inquire in both locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Meta, for several reasons:

1. Blogs are good for occasional announcements, but once it scrolls off the front page, it's impossible to find, unless you already know what you are looking for.
2. Meta is designed and intended for support, and contains all of the machinery to do it properly. The blog isn't, and doesn't.
3. The Atwood<sup>TM</sup> uses Meta for support, not the blog.